# Compress multiple files in different folders

Tags: compression

Could someone help me with compressing thousands of files?
I have a lot of folders and a lot of files in these folders, i would like to know if it's possible to compress each file separately.
Foe example, folder 01 has folder 02 and 2 files in it, folder 02 has 2 files in it. I need to compress all files in all folders and leave these archives right where original files were.

Thank you!

[image: multiple files in different folders]

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can open up Terminal from inside your computer's `/Applications/Utilities` folder. Then change to the root directory containing all the other directories you want to zip the files in by typing this command:

`cd /path/to/folder01`

(replace `/path/to/folder01` with wherever the folder is on your hard drive - it will give you the right path if you simply drag the folder icon from your Finder, right into the Terminal window.)

then type this command:

`find . -type f -execdir zip '{}.zip' '{}' \; -delete`

This will compress all files (not directories) within the directory tree starting with the folder `/folder01`, leaving the `.zip` in the same directory as the original, and delete the originals.

If for some reason you don't want to delete the originals but rather leave them in place next to the `.zip` archives, you can omit the `-delete` at the end.

I would recommend backing up the entire directory tree you're running this on first before trying it, just in case you make a typo or anything goes wrong. This worked as described for me, but you mess around in Terminal on your computer at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting, @Allan. Wasn't sure of the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, [Stuffit](http://www.stuffit.com) Deluxe has this feature. There is an option to create individual archive files in the “Compression” preferences.